# installing phplot using cakephp3 wamp64

Tags: php, cakephp

I have some issues installing phplot on windows (wamp64) for a cakephp3 application. The instructions indicate

```
"On Windows systems, you can simply download the release ZIP file, expand
   it using Windows Explorer, and copy the needed script file(s) out of 
 the contained phplot-* folder into place."
```

q1)Where exactly is "into place mean" on wamp64?

q2) accessing  phplot in cakephp3 projects (I cant find instructions)?

`http://phplot.sourceforge.net/phplotdocs/install-install.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use composer for the same. Execute this command inside your project directory to install it.

```
composer require davefx/phplot
```

OR add this line in your projects composer.json file in require section.

```
"davefx/phplot": "*"
```

and the execute `composer update` command.

OR you can also unzip phplot zip file inside your vendor directory and then include it in your controller by using below command

```
 require_once(ROOT . 'vendor' . DS  . 'phplot-6.2.0' . DS . 'phplot.php');
```

Comment: I am not getting this to work. I have a project called 'crm' and I unzip the phplot in this folder or in the website folder www? I tried both and composer kept saying 'could not find package' Its all there though

Comment: Have you installed cakephp 3?

Comment: yes i have everything installed and I am using a currently working cakephp3 project.  This seemed to work though in the controller  require_once(ROOT  . DS  . 'phplot-6.2.0' . DS . 'phplot.php');

Comment: you need to unzip the folder inside crm/vendor folder.. and the include it like  require_once(ROOT . 'vendor' . DS  . 'phplot-6.2.0' . DS . 'phplot.php');

Comment: I coildnt get the hello world to work . I dont get an error just unreadable chars http://phplot.sourceforge.net/phplotdocs/starting-simple.html